# Unexpected voltage drop in the output

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I've created a power converter based on an LM5085 IC. The converter was designed so that it can work with 24V in the input. Here is my schematic.
[image]

Requirements:
VIN - 24V
Vout - 3.3V
Imax = 1A
Imin = 0.1A

Layout:

[image]

The red line is a trace in another layer

The problems is that when the input voltage reaches 20V, the output voltage drops to almost 0V and the converter stops working. I've tested it for different values of RT, RSEN and inductors, even with a different layout but it didn't solve my problem.

What are your thoughts on that circuit?

Comment: D79 is a diode and Vr is about 21V.

Comment: How those component values were calculated? What parameters you used to calculate them? Have you double checked the calculations? And can the inductor handle the peak current without saturating and triggering the overcurrent protection?

Comment: Blue Cloud, I checked the datasheet of that diode. I replaced it with a simple silicon diode. It works excellent now. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: @Justme I used WEBENCH for calculation. In my circuit, the converter doesn't even reach the maximum current value. Thank you for your suggestions.